# Using Jsoup to submit a form that has select inputs in Android

Tags: android-studio, post, jsoup

Hi guys I am new to Android App development. I am currently trying to develop an app that shows the route of two places and I found out the data from https://mrt.sg/fare is quite useful for me. The form of the page contains two select type inputs and a submit button. I tried to use Jsoup to fill and submit the form and get the result, but I couldn't. This is my code.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Content content = new Content();
    content.execute();
}

private class Content extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
        super.onCancelled(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            /*
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://mrt.sg/fare").get();
            Elements options = doc.select("select#stn_a>option");
            for (Element option : options) {
                System.out.println("label: " + option.text() + ", value: " + option.attr("value"));
            }
            Log.d("","doc: " +doc);
             */

            Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://mrt.sg/fare")
                    .data("stn_a", "hj").data("stn_b", "zl").method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
            Document doc = res.parse();
            String data = doc.select("div#results_tripcalc").text();
            Log.d("Result","result: " +data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send your data exactly as your web browser submits it.
To check what's acutally sent I used Chrome's debugger with Network tab open. Then I fill the form and click "Calculate fare". Now debugger shows the POST was sent to URL: `https://mrt.sg/tripcalc` and parameters were:

```
station_a: id
station_b: bv
```

[image]

I tweaked your code to do this and it works correctly:

```
  Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://mrt.sg/tripcalc")
                                 .data("station_a", "hj")
                                 .data("station_b", "zl")
                                 .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                                 .execute();
```